# How to access the elements of a C struct with an index

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct like so:

```
struct pvtFlags {  
    uint8_t gnssFixOK : 1;  
    uint8_t diffSoln : 1;  
    uint8_t psmState : 3;  
    uint8_t headVehValid : 1;  
    uint8_t carrSoln : 2;  
};

struct pvtFlags {  
    uint8_t gnssFixOK : 1;  
    uint8_t diffSoln : 1;  
    uint8_t psmState : 3;  
    uint8_t headVehValid : 1;  
    uint8_t carrSoln : 2;  
};

struct pvtFlags2 {
    uint8_t reserved : 5;
    uint8_t confirmedAvai : 1;
    uint8_t confirmedDate : 1;
    uint8_t confirmedTime : 1;
};

struct pvtFlags3 {
    uint16_t invalidLlh : 1;
    uint16_t lastCorrectionAge : 3;
    uint16_t reserved : 12;
};

struct pvt {
    uint32_t itow;
    uint16_t year;
    uint8_t month;
    uint8_t day;
    uint8_t hour;
    uint8_t min;
    uint8_t sec;
    struct pvtValid valid;
    uint32_t tAcc;
    int32_t nano;
    uint8_t fixType;
    struct pvtFlags flags;
    struct pvtFlags2 flags2;
    uint8_t numSV;
    double lon;
    double lat;
    float height;
    float hMSL;
    float hAcc;
    float vAcc;
    float ve1N;
    float ve1E;
    float ve1D;
    float gSpeed;
    float headMot;
    float sAcc;
    float headAcc;
    float pDOP;
    struct pvtFlags3 flags3;
    uint32_t reserved0;
    float headVeh;
    float magDec;
    float magAcc;
};
```

As you can see, its a bunch of different types with different sizes, now I have an `int` array with 33 elements (the number of struct members) consisting of ones and zeros, for true and false, and I want to run a loop on that array and do something with the corresponding i'th element in the struct if it is a one, something else if it is a zero. As the title says, need to somehow access this with the index, like the order it is in inside the struct.

I've tried to pass a pointer to the first element then increment that pointer but that wouldn't work since the elements aren't a fixed size, and this is a micro-controller with like 128KBs of memory so I dont really wanna make all of them into doubles then increase the pointer 8 by 8, that would be WAY too wasteful.

Comment: So assign them one by one? Overall, consider _not_ using any bitfields, and write setters and getters using bit operations instead. `with the corresponding i'th element in the struct if its a one` You showed 4 structures. Corresponding which structure? Research X macros. Consider code generation or C++ or rust.

Comment: Bit-fields don't have a well-defined allocation order. Otherwise for any chunk of raw data, you can access bit number `bit` by `data[bit/8] & (1u << bit%8)`.

Comment: OT: You have two `struct pvtFlags` and no `struct pvtValid`

Comment: "... somehow access this with the index, like the order it is in inside the struct." Well, C has no support for that.

Comment: You have a problem with your project design.

Comment: Feels like an xy problem...

Comment: To me this question is unclear. You write "... do something with the corresponding i'th element in the struct if its a one, something else if its a zero" Can add more details about what "something" is? Is it different actions for all members? Is it the same for all members? Is it the same for all members of same type? etc...

Comment: To me it's also unclear how you'll handle the struct members. You do have 33 members in `struct pvt` but 4 of them are structs each containing a number of members. So in principle you have more than 33 named variables. Maybe we can help if you provide more details about what you want to do.

Comment: Which action do you plan to perform on each element and what information does that require? - Do you need a pointer to the element and size/type?

Comment: A `struct` type is not an array, so you cannot iterate over its members like an array. Even if you could treat struct members like array elements, accessing an array element involves dereferencing a pointer to the element. Bit-field members are not addressable, so you cannot point to them.

Comment: See [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) for information on what an XY problem is.

Comment: AFAICS, you've not shown what a `struct pvtValid` looks like, though your main structure contains one. You show two consecutive `struct pvtFlags` definitions; that won't compile. Maybe the first of those should be `struct pvtValid` with the appropriate content? If you're going to manage an array, you're going to need a complex structure to identify the elements of the array. It seems likely that the code to manage that will be bigger than simply using direct access. You might be able to use a union to access the set of adjacent `float` values. You probably have padding bytes in `struct pvt`.

Comment: You need a getter function `int get_elem(struct pvt *p, int n)`. Consider using [Xmacro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_macro) to make implementation simpler and easier to maintain.

Comment: You can construct an array of the offsets of all the members (`offsetof` can help), and use that to locate struct members by index.  But Your members don't all have the same data type, so the "something" and "something else" that you want to do in any individual case would need to be aware of and sensitive to the actual data type of each member.  It seems likely that by the time you sort *that* out, there will be little, if any, remaining net gain from your idea of accessing members by index (if ever there was any in the first place).